# cumulative summing/sorting javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have an array that looks like this.

```
var data = [
    {beb: 200, cre: 0, id: 'A1'},
    {beb: 0, cre: 200, id: 'A2'},
    {beb: 0, cre: 100, id: 'A4'},
    {beb: 0, cre: 100, id: 'A3'},
]
```

How would I make this look something like this?

```
var newData = [
    {deb: 200, cre: 0, total: 200, id: 'A1'},
    {deb: 0, cre: 200, total: 0, id: 'A2'},
    {deb: 0, cre: 100, total: -100, id: 'A3'},
    {deb: 0, cre: 100, total: -200, id: 'A4'},
]
```

What is important is that the array needs to be sorted on id first and then the total is calculated on deb - cre + the total from the previous row.

I'm currently using d3 in my setup but I haven't been able to find a good solution for this, the calculated total doesn't get saved on the correct object, probably because the sorting get's wrong inside the loop.

so if there is a clean solution for this using d3 I would be really happy because then I could easily use map or key if I add other attributes later.

thanks.

**Edit**

```
var calc = [];
var count = 0;

var newArr = data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.id - b.id;
})

for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    var item = newArr[i];
    count += item.deb - item.cred
    calc.push({deb: item.deb, cre: item.deb, total: count, id: item.id })
}
```

for the sort part I have tried both `a.id - b.id` and `b.id - a.id`

one problem with this is that it doesn't seem to be done in the order I need, and using this way I have no easy way of mapping it with d3.js so I would prefer a solution using that instead.

Comment: Post the code you wrote to attempt this and explain what specific part isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to http://stackoverflow.com . We love to help people provided we see what they've implemented already

Comment: downvotes.. really??

Comment: Yeah downvotes! Your original question had no code, you didn't describe what you attempted, you didn't explain what specific part was giving you trouble -  all you did was say "Hey, here's what I want - How can I do it?" That's about as broad and general as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    // to sort by number
    // we need to get the number of the id first
    // if the id will also change the part before the number this will have to be adjusted (just use the search)
    var aid = parseInt(a.id.replace(/[^\d]/, ''), 10),
        bid = parseInt(b.id.replace(/[^\d]/, ''), 10);

    return aid - bid;
}).map(function(d, idx, arr) {
    // now we can calculate the total value

    // previous data entry, or if it is the first round, a fake object
    var previousData = (arr[idx - 1] || {"total": 0});

    // calc the total value
    d.total = (d.beb - d.cre) + previousData.total;
    return d;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43fsk7b2/)